# Templated member variable with constraints, cannot cast, why?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

All,

I have the following class definition:

```
public class SessionScope<TSession> : ISessionScope<TSession>
        where TSession : class, IStatefulSession
    {
        private TSession _session; // Constraint as IStatefulSession
    }
```

Then why I cannot do this cast:

```
_session = HibernateContext.Current.AcquireNewSession(); // AcquireNewSession() returns IStatefulSession
```

This is the compiler message:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxx.Persistence.IStatefulSession' to 'TSession'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But I can do this:

```
_session = (TSession)HibernateContext.Current.AcquireNewSession();
```

Comment: You don't show a complete [mcve] so I'm guessing a little here.  `TSession` is an `IStatefulSession` but it may be more, it may be some class that implements many additional interfaces and have many unrelated members.  So if `HibernateContext.Current.AcquireNewSession()` merely returns something of type `IStatefulSession` then we don't know it can be assigned to `TSession`.  All we know is that something of type `TSession` is assignable to something of type `IStatefulSession`.

Comment: Makes sense, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

The short version is basically that `AcquireNewSession` returns an interface `IStatefulSession`, which is less specific than `TSession`, a class implementing that interface.

You have to explicitly cast the less specific type to the more specific type, which is possible because of the given constraint.

Going the other way, however, is always fine, because we can always assign the more specific type to a less specific type.

It's basically the same reason you can always assign a `string` to an `object` variable, but you have to explicitly cast an `object` if you want to assign it to a `string` variable.